# Sets invariant under isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an isometry. Is it true that $f(U) \subseteq U$ implies that  $U \subseteq f(U)$ for an arbitrary subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

It is intuitively clear to me that $U$ and $f(U)$ must have the same "shape", so my guess is that if $f(U)$ is a subset of $U$ then the converse should also be true. I know it's a very simple statement but I haven't been able to prove it (so either my intuition is incorrect or I am missing something important). Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If $n=1$ and $f(x)=x+1$, then $f(\Bbb N)\subset\Bbb N$, but $\Bbb N\not\subset f(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: Do you have any other hypotheses on $U$, like boundedness for example?

Comment: I think you need boundedness. You can imagine translating a halfplane $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha) \subset \alpha$. If the set is bounded then it might work.

Comment: @DerekAllums I do, actually. What I am actually trying to solve is exercise 11 from section 4-2 of do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces", which states that if $U$ is a regular surface and $f(U) \subseteq U$ then the restriction of $f$ to $U$ is an isometry of $S$. That being said, I can see how José's counterexample generalizes for regular surfaces, so I think $f$ is simply supposed to induce an isometry from S onto its image (with $f(U)$ not necessarily being equal to $U$).

Comment: @BeniBogosel I can see how it could work for bounded sets, but would it also not hold for some classes unbounded sets (like paraboloids, for example)?